# Libreoffice and crossfunctional flowcharts

Tags: libreoffice

I have to create a crossfunctional flowchart for a given task. It is explained how to do in Microsoft Visio, but I can't activate that because my pc is offline and is going to be for a long time. Libreoffice is the best alternate I could find, but here I can't find the way of defining custom properties for the shapes. It seems to be vital for analyizing the bp itself so I can't work without it. Is it possible to create such flowcharts in Libreoffice Draw? Or it supports only drawing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about Libreoffice, but here is [the tool](http://www.conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/cross-functional-flowcharts) where are lots of free templates and libraries for cross-functional flowcharting

Not free (about 199 usd or less, but has free trial period and free support)

Comment: Thanks, great tool.. btw, its trial version is fully functional